# How to resolve - unable to cast Generic.List to Linq.IQueryable using Automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, automapper

I'm getting the following error in using a DTO and EF model:

> Unable to cast object  of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Core.UI.Models.ContentTypes]'
>   to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Core.UI.Models.ContentTypes]

Bootstrapped: `Mapper.CreateMap<ContentType, Project.Core.UI.Models.ContentTypes>();`

In an OData controller method `public IQueryable<ContentTypes> Get() {...}`, using:

```
var result = Mapper.Map<IQueryable<ContentType>, IQueryable<ContentTypes>>(_repository.Query().Get()
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Description));
```

I have also tried the following but I suspect that this is exactly what the above is as well:

```
var result =_repository.Query().Get()
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Description);
var dto = Mapper.Map<IQueryable<ContentType>, IQueryable<ContentTypes>>(result);
return dto;
```

How can I create the appropriate mapping for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be aware of the fact that by creating your mapping in such a way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContentType, Project.Core.UI.Models.ContentTypes>();
```

Only these basic generic collection types are supported implicitly:

```
IEnumerable
IEnumerable<T>
ICollection
ICollection<T>
IList
IList<T>
List<T>
Arrays
```

But not `IQueryable<T>`. That's why you get the exception.

Therefore you should try doing sth like this:

```
var dto = Mapper.Map
         <IEnumerable<ContentType>, 
          IEnumerable<ContentTypes>>(result.AsEnumerable()); 
// or e.g. List/List/ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what bejger said you can also use the [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) namespace in Automapper to map IQueryable objects, but it puts some [limitations](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#wiki-supported-mapping-options) on what setup you can do between two object when you do your `CreateMap<TSource, TDest>`

instead of using it like

```
IQueryable<ContentTypes> dto = Mapper.Map<IQueryable<ContentType>, IQueryable<ContentTypes>>(result);
```

you instead use it like

```
IQueryable<ContentTypes> dto = result.Project().To<ContentTypes>();
```

Comment: Where does `Project()` come from in this case?  Result doesn't have any reference to it.

Comment: To use both `Project()` and `To<T>()` you need to add `using  AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;` to the top of your file. [It is included with Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'ProjectTo' method instead.

```
var result = iQueryableResultSet.ProjectTo<MyObjectName>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Optionally you pass the ConfigurationProvider from any injected Mapper instance, as necessary.